# How to test route changes with NextJS, Vitest, and React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-testing-library, vitest

What is the best way to test routing in a NextJS app? I am using it as a static site generator and am not really using any server-side rendered capability. How do I test routing for the entire application? Ex, let's say my site starts on the route `/first-route` and I fire an event that changes the route to `/second-route`. How should I test that? I am trying to use Vitest and React Testing Library. I would really appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky. You may want to consider using something like [Cypress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress) for these tests as they are more like end-to-end tests. (It's 2023 now, I'd recommend [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) over Cypress!)

You may get away with a tool like [next-page-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-page-tester) - though in my experience that causes more problems than it solves for complex apps.

But if you just want to test that *something happens* when the path changes, I've had good results with [next-router-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-router-mock). There's plenty of options available in their docs, but a simple example might look like this:

```
import mockRouter from "next-router-mock";
describe('tests', () => {
  it('changes the url', () => {
    mockRouter.setCurrentUrl("/pizza");
  })
})
```